# Was Lily Potter pregnant when she was murdered?

Tags: harry-potter

There was a rumour not long ago that did the rounds on social media and blogging sites, claiming that Lily Potter was pregnant when she was killed. This is of course something that is never mentioned in the books, but that doesn't necessarily make it untrue.

Has J.K. Rowling ever addressed this rumour to confirm or deny it? And if it has been confirmed, is there anything to suggest this had any effect on the protective charm which was placed on Harry when she died?

Comment: Lily Potter may well have been pregnant, but there are no indications of this in the HP books, any of JKR's subsequent writings, nor has the author ever made a statement confirming this rumour.

Comment: If there is zero context in the book, or anywhere else, I see this being Primarily Opinion Based / fan theory discussion.Could you provide some the context in which the rumor was started?

Comment: @Skooba - I've seen it on "HP facts", a notoriously inaccurate list of real and fake facts mixed in with each other (possibly maliciously, possibly just through incompetence). I can't find any earlier reference but that doesn't mean there isn't one, just that I can't find it.

Comment: I don't think there is any evidence for this.

Comment: Just wait until JK Rowling gets bored and is out of the news for a little, tweet this to her, then she will no doubt retweet it as canon.

Comment: It looks like something I read at fanfiction, doubt it is true tho

Comment: This question seems to be attracting a lot of downvotes, which I don't think it deserves. It's a good question, just not too well worded. I've edited it to make it seem less opinion-based and more like a neutral question; I hope you don't mind, @maguire.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's certainly possible (heck, anything's *possible*), but there's absolutely no **evidence** that this rumour is anything other than pure fan-fiction.

There's nothing in the <s>seven</s> ten HP books to indicate that Lily Potter was pregnant, nor has J.K. Rowling issued any post-facto [statements](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=inurl:http:%2F%2Fwww.accio-quote.org%2F%20%22lily%22%20AND%20%22pregnant%22) that would imply that that was the case, nor has she issued any [twits](https://twitter.com/search?q=second%20OR%20child%20from%3Ajk_rowling&src=typd&lang=en) that speak to this issue.

As hard as it is to prove a negative, without any kind of proof, I think we can call this one debunked.

Comment: There’s usually some signs, right?

Comment: @Bellatrix - Certainly in the film there's zero indication

Comment: Thanks so much! :) (By the way, I’m sorry - I was sleepy and I thought this post was about something else, my apologies.) Anyway, I approve of this answer, have an upvote! :)

Answer (score -1):

### She was almost certainly not noticeably pregnant

Harry saw his mother on multiple occasions in *Deathly Hallows*, yet he never said or did anything to indicate that she looked even remotely pregnant. For instance, he saw her in Voldemort's memory, moments before her death:

> A door opened and the mother entered, saying words he could not hear, her long dark-red hair falling over her face. Now the father scooped up the son and handed him to the mother. He threw his wand down upon the sofa and stretched, yawning....

He also saw a picture of her in Snape's memory, from shortly before she died:

> Snape took the page bearing Lily's signature, and her love, and tucked it inside his robes. Then he ripped in two the photograph he was also holding, so that he kept the part from which Lily laughed, throwing the portion showing James and Harry back onto the floor, under the chest of drawers....

Had Harry seen that she was pregnant he surely would have said something. We can therefore presumably safely conclude that Lily was not noticeably pregnant at the time she died.